# Graticiel : reconnu on non ?

Tags: usage, informatique

Le mot-valise construit sur le modèle de l'anglais freeware avec les mots « gratis » et « logiciel (wiki) est-il reconnu ? Son usage est-il répandu ? Pourrait-on confondre le mot avec le gratte-ciel (prononciations similaires) ?

Comment: Moi j'ai eu connu *grat**U**iciel*... après... j'ai vieilli... bien sûr! Et les mots avec... sans doute.

Comment: Gratuiciel ou graticiel selon l’[OQLF](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299144).

Comment: Ça fait longtemps (très longtemps) que c'est dans les dictionnaires. [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gratuiciel) et [ici](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/Gratuiciel/fr-fr/) Dans un [article de **2002**](https://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-102369-difference-entre-gratuiciel-et-partagiciel).

Comment: @Montéedelait En France on dit plutôt gratuiciel.

Comment: @Laure ...au Québec aussi, plutôt gratuiciel.

Comment: @Laure J'ai constaté que un pourcentage significatif de mon entourage ne le reconnaît pas:-)! Merci pour le commentaire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Le mot-valise construit sur le modèle de l'anglais freeware avec les mots « gratis » et « logiciel (wiki) est-il reconnu ?

Oui, les mots *gratuiciel* et *graticiel* sont connus ou facilement  compréhensibles, dans le milieu informatique au moins. Il y a cependant très souvent une confusion/ambiguïté entre les *freewares*, les *sharewares* (partagiciels), les logiciels libres (*free software*), les logiciels *open source* (code source ouvert) et les logiciels du domain public (*public domain software*).

> Son usage est-il répandu ?

Pas vraiment. Je ne rencontre jamais *grat(u)iciel* à l'oral où c'est soit *freeware*, soit *logiciel gratuit* qui prévaut. Ils sont aussi distancés à l'écrit :

[image]

> Pourrait-on confondre le mot avec le gratte-ciel (prononciations similaires) ?

Non. Les prononciations sont clairement distinctes, deux syllabes pour *gratte-ciel* contre trois pour *gratuiciel/graticiel*.